# How to create Meteor password from Java?

Tags: java, meteor, bcrypt

I am trying to generate a valid Meteor password from Java code.

I know Meteor uses bcrypt and it seems to run a SHA-256 hash in front. But I cannot get this to work. Has anybody out there done that successfully? I tried things like:

```
String password = "secret123";
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
Charset scs = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
//Charset scs = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
byte[] encodedhash = digest.digest(password.getBytes(scs));
String hash = new String(encodedhash, scs);
String bcrypt = BCrypt.hashpw(hash, BCrypt.gensalt());
```

This returns a string that looks like a valid bcrypt password, but Meteor does not accept it after I store it in the MongoDB and try to log in from the Meteor code.

Comment: Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: It does not fail. It produces a string that looks like a valid bcrypt password but something is wrong (some encryption along the way, probably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The binary result of the SHA-256 has to be formatted into a string of hex digits.

This is the working code:

```
String password = "secret123";
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
Charset scs = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
byte[] encodedhash = digest.digest(password.getBytes(scs));
String hash = toHexString(encodedhash);
String bcrypt = BCrypt.hashpw(hash, BCrypt.gensalt());
```

With toHexString as follows:

```
    private static char toHex(int nibble) {
        final char[] hexDigit = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
        return hexDigit[nibble & 0xF];
    }
    public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(bytes.length*2);
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(toHex(bytes[i] >> 4) );
            sb.append(toHex(bytes[i]) );
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I want to generate the same password generated by meteor password, above code is creating different

Comment: These are salted passwords, you will hardly ever get the same string. You have to actually test if you can log in, and that works fine for me with the code above.

Comment: ... or use crypt.BCryptVerify(password, storedHash) where the "password" would be the hex encoded one as created above.